# angular ignores my routing view controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

When i click on a link such as

```
<a  ui-sref ="memostate({type:'memo' , subject:'part/abc' })">
```

my routing works fine, and my browser loads for instance:

```
"localhost:75/memo?subject=part/abc"
```

The template gets all its {{}} bindings resolved.

as my state is defined as

```js
.state({
  name: 'memostate',
  url: '/:type' + '?' + ':subject/',
  views: {
    'resultPage': {
      templateUrl: "memoView.html",
      controller: 'memoController'
    }
  },
})
```

however when i paste in or reload that exact link, my state controller gets ignored. It does get downloaded from the server because I have the script tag on the template, but none of my braces get resolved. It is pretty peculiar..

If i define the url of my state with that exact link as well, it does not work.
If i remove the memostate and write `ng-controller="memoController"` in my template, the html template page still shows up with no bindings resolved; even though the controller still shows up downloaded in the dev tools network tab.

Is it a server side issue? how can i tell the template to use that controller.

Any idea?

Comment: is the problem routing to there on click or controller not loading correctly? add controller definition.

Comment: it does not, and also if i remove the state and paste the script within the template in a script tag inside the template, it does not work as well. weird